# VisNetwork: How to color edges using HeatMap?

Tags: r, igraph, sna, visnetwork, ggraph

Let's have a data frame containing edges and their weights as follows.

```
> data <- data.frame(From = sample(1:10,15,replace = T),
+                    To = sample(1:10,15,replace = T),
+                    Weight = runif(15,min = 0,max = 1))
> data
   From To    Weight
1     3  1 0.4846809
2     5  5 0.3007253
3     3  9 0.4345911
4     4  6 0.2100013
5     9  9 0.6778775
6     7  9 0.6316653
7     5  3 0.2996755
8     6  3 0.4550394
9     3  9 0.3162794
10    7  1 0.7933087
11    9  2 0.3738579
12    9  4 0.9152347
13    1  3 0.6452292
14    8  3 0.3732314
15    6  8 0.9751309
```

I constructed, the graph using **Igraph** library as follows.

```
> g <- graph.data.frame(data,directed = F)
> g
IGRAPH a2074bf UN-- 9 15 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), Weight (e/n)
+ edges from a2074bf (vertex names):
 [1] 3--1 5--5 3--9 4--6 9--9 9--7 3--5 3--6 3--9 7--1 9--2 4--9 3--1 3--8 6--8
```

I tried it a little bit and color the edges according to their weight range. Below is my code, where I colored the edges as **Purple** if they have a weight between 0.4 to 1. Here is my code to color the edges.

```
#Network Visualization
mycolor <- ifelse(E(g)$Weight>=0.04,"purple",
                   ifelse(E(g)$Weight>=0.001,"green",
                          ifelse(E(g)$Weight>=0.00001,"brown",
                                 ifelse(E(g)$Weight>=0.000007,"blue",
                      ifelse(E(g)$Weight>=0.00000001,"red","black")))))

nodes <- data.frame(id = V(g)$name, title = V(g)$name)
edges <- get.data.frame(g, what="edges")[1:2]
edges$color <- mycolor
visNetwork(nodes, edges,main = "Network Visualization")
```

The issue with this coloring scheme is that

1. Group of edges has the same color i.e., the edges with a weight between 0.4 to 1 will have **Purple** color. However, I want to color each edge differently according to its weight.
2. If I assign colors manually, then it will create a disturbance in the legend. Also will be difficult to interpret and find the edges with high weight.

Now, I want to visualize the network with the **VisNetwork** library. And want to color the edges according to their weight. I found that **HeatMap** coloring is best for values in Weight. Is there any way to color the edges using the **HeatMap** functionality? Also want to add a color tray to the legend.

Moreover,

1. I need to add legend as follows with range 0 to 1.
2. [image]
3. Also if you have a solution using any other library, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper answer, but close to the solution. For the coloring, we need to generate colors according to the **Weights**. We can generate colors through this function.

```
genkolor <- function(w) {
   k <- vector()
   for (i in 1:length(w)) {
      k[i] <- rgb(1 - w[i],1 - w[i],1 - w[i])
   }
   return(k)
}
```

Now, assign the color to edges as follows.

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = V(g)$name, title = V(g)$name)
edges <- get.data.frame(g, what="edges")[1:2]
nodes$shape <- "circle"
nodes$label <- nodes$id
edges$width <- 6
edges$label <- E(g)$Weight
edges$color <- genkolor(E(g)$Weight)
visNetwork(nodes,edges,main = "Network Visualization") %>%
   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_nicely")
```

Here is the output. Where black is the max weight color and white is the min weight color.

[image]